# How to use IF condition in select query to display a column that is not null

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I want to display a column in a select query according to the following :

1- If result is not null, display the column.

2- If the result is null, do not display the column.

I tried this but it doesn't work, it displays all the time the column (null or not null)

```
select 
 if(surname  is null,'',surname) as surname
from my_table
```

Comment: You can't delete a whole column just based on a null value of one of it's rows. How would you display the other rows that have a surname. If you intention is to just display nothing in the column if the surname is null, your statement should work correctly.

Comment: If all the rows are null, do not display the column, else if at least there is one result not nul, then display the column

Comment: That's not possible. You can't delete a column if it's in the SELECT-statement. The SQL doesn't check if all columns are null and omit the column. You will have to do yourself in your program.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL if you want to enforce this at the database level.  Or, as @Rik mentioned, you code enforce this in the application which is calling MySQL.

Comment: I am using this query in a complicated script,
Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want an example... here it is.
B.T.W. this example has multiple columns (id and givenname). If you only have that one surname column you could do this a whole other way but it would depend on the rest of your "script" how you would do it. (because the select would not return ANY columns in that case and that's invalid for a select)

Data

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
 id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 surname VARCHAR(20),
 givenname VARCHAR(20),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO my_table(givenname, surname) VALUES
("me", null),
("you", null),
(null, null),
("and sombody else", null);
```

Dynamic SQL

```
SET @nr_names = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE NOT(surname IS null));
SET @fields = (SELECT if(@nr_names=0, "id, givenname", "id, givenname, surname"));
SET @query = CONCAT("select ", @fields, " from my_table");
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Will result in

```
1   me
2   you
3   (null)
4   and sombody else
```

Chaning the data to

```
INSERT INTO my_table(givenname, surname) VALUES
("me", null),
("you", "works"),
(null, null),
("and sombody else", null);
```

You get

```
1   me                (null)
2   you               works
3   (null)            (null)
4   and sombody else  (null)
```

[Working SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7def7c)
<sub>(unfortunately SQL Fiddle isn't what it used to be with the lack of speed these days)</sub>

I can't get SQL Fiddle to work anymore.
Here is the alternative: [RexTester](http://rextester.com/OYPJNH35357)
See there is no column surname. Change one null to text in the insert data and click "Run it".

Answer (score 0):

**Edited as per comments**

If you want to display the last name column if one or more values is NOT NULL, then you can use the following IF/ELSE statement:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(last_name) from people) > (0)
  SELECT first_name, last_name from people;
ELSE
  SELECT first_name from people;
```

Note that you're not checking if "value IS NULL" or "value=NULL" in the WHERE clause of the COUNT - MSSQL, and I assume other versions too, do **not** count 'null' as a value.

Schema 1 (for the IF/ELSE above):

```
create table people (first_name varchar(20), last_name varchar(20));
insert into people (first_name, last_name) values ('Mary', 'Smith');
insert into people (first_name, last_name) values ('Mark', 'Jones');
insert into people (first_name, last_name) values ('Michael', null);
```

Schema 2, with an IF/ELSE if you want to run it:

```
create table people_no_surnames (first_name varchar(20), last_name varchar(20));
insert into people_no_surnames (first_name, last_name) values ('Mary', null);
insert into people_no_surnames (first_name, last_name) values ('Mark', null);
insert into people_no_surnames (first_name, last_name) values ('Michael', null);

    IF (SELECT COUNT(last_name) from people_no_surnames) > (0)
  SELECT first_name, last_name from people_no_surnames;
ELSE
  SELECT first_name from people_no_surnames;
```

The first schema will return both columns (note there will still be a NULL in the surname column, so if you wanted to replace it with an empty string, you'd have to put that in the SELECT statement), the second schema returns only the first_name column.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you test this yourself in MySQL? MySQL doesn't support [IF Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) as direct command (or at least in my version). It needs to be in a stored procedure/function. Try it in http://rextester.com/

Comment: Whup, my bad, didn't see OP tagged their post as MySQL. This code does work in SQl Server tho ;)

Comment: Yep. B.T.W. you still have an error in your people_no_surnames SQL. You check if `COUNT(last_name) > COUNT(*)` which can never be true !! You should have done `IF (SELECT COUNT(last_name) from people_no_surnames) > 0` as IF statement (in both cases). See here for an example: http://rextester.com/USJEO91380 (you can change it so there is one surname and you see the column appear) (Luckily rextester has an option for SQL Server too :) )

Comment: I've been taught 'it works on my machine' is no excuse - but this does work as expected in SSMS 2012, in so far as I tested it. But I have been silly there. I'll update answer accordingly.